# Bootstrap navbar on hover list item remove class active, on mouse out return class active

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can you help me how to do realize this situation with the bootstrap navbar. As I wrote in the title, I need to realize when click on list item in navbar menu, current item should get class active and marked with top border, but on hover over other list item, class active (border top also) should disappear from current list item with active class..

Practically, when the mouse is moving over the menu the red line follows the mouse. when the mouse moves away from the menu item, the red line return back above the active menu

This is my current code - http://www.bootply.com/uvUwueNuOG

You'll noticed that is Home card active, when hover, active class disappear and move depending on where the mouse is, but when click on another card in menu, nothing happens

Comment: Many frameworks and/or themes provide functionality or styling based on whether an element has the class `active` or not. If you only want to style an element, consider naming your class anything else, not `active`. Use class `active` when you actually want to activate something, not when you want to color it. Same goes for other classes, like `menu`, `menu-item`, `open`, `invisible`, etc... Stay away from commonly used English web related terms and you'll be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems because you should not add/remove the active class unless you want to make a certain element "active". So, first step is not to remove `.active` from the "active" element when you hover another. If you want the `.active` element to lose its `border-top-color`, you need to put this in your CSS:

```
.navbar-default:hover .navbar-nav>.active:not(:hover) > a {
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

Make sure it loads after `bootstrap.css` or you will need a stronger selector. Now the `active` item no longer looks `active` when the menu is hovered. Now, using JavaScript, you can just use the `active` class as it is supposed to be used: to mark the active element. So when you want to make another element active, you remove it from all elements and apply it to the one you clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.navbar-default li').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-default li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
});
```

Good enough?

Comment: Exactly that, this is the best solution so far, just needs a little fix. On hover over active item also, border top disappears, but should not be.

Comment: Excellent Andrei, but I forgot to tell you what else is going on. Try to hover anywhere outside .navbar-nav and you'll noticed that the same thing happens, which is a problem. there should be no interaction when you do the hover outside navbar-nav which in this case is not good

Comment: With all due respect, that is not my problem. I can easily solve it, just like I solved all your requests so far, but this has to stop. I'm currently available for hire, but not on StackOverflow. My role here is to help people better understand web design concepts and, in general, improve their overall techniques. I am here because I learned from others and want to return the favor and help others become better web-designers. That's why I always explain the principle. But I am NOT here to provide free web design services. Have a great day.

Comment: ok, but do not understand the point of your solution at all. What is the logic of your solution, when you hover over the logo, flag or button (because it's all in .navbar-default), red border should disappear. http://prnt.sc/djff1w

Comment: The point of my solution was to answer your request. After I provided the solution you realized the initial request was incomplete and you made another request, with more specific requirements. From my point of view, you are not here to learn, but to get free solutions. You haven't made any effort to understand what I'm doing. No effort to learn. Since you are not willing to learn, I am not willing to teach. That's my point.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this... it will open a popup on class remove and class re-adding just for confirmation you can remove alert from there. in this example i used your code just replaced .hover with .mouseenter and for leave .mouseleave

Please try now this is adding active class on click as well..

```js
//Add class active on specific list item
$(document).ready(function(){

    var item, elem, makeActive;
    item = '.navbar-nav li.item';

    elem = document.querySelectorAll(item);

    makeActive = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
            elem[i].classList.remove('active');

            this.classList.add('active');
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
        elem[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);

    var $home = $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active");
 
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav li").mouseenter(function () {
        $home.removeClass("active");
     // alert('active class removed')
    })
 .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $home.addClass("active");
      // alert('active class readded')
    });
  
   $(".navbar-nav li").click(function () {
         $(this).addClass("active");
    });
  
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 23px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Lustria', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 33px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

h4 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus,
input[type]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #353d4a inset;
}

/********** HEADER ****************/

.navbar-default {
    border: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar > .container .navbar-brand.shrink {
    height: 52px;
    background: #403f44;
}
.navbar-brand>img.shrink {
    width: 46%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 35px 0px 0px;
    transition: 0s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    padding: 22px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .item>a.shrink {
    padding: 12px 10px 14px;

}

.nav.navbar-nav .language a.shrink {
    margin-top: 14px;
}

.navbar-default .booking .btn-default.shrink {
    top: 3px;
}

.navbar-default .booking .btn-default a.shrink {
    padding: 12px 22.5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #3e3e3e;
    background: none;
    border-top-color: #ff2a00;
}

.nav.navbar-nav .language a {
    border-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 27px 18px 0px 20px;
}

.navbar-default .language img {
    margin-right: 26px;
}

.language.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:after {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 52px;
    top: 4px;
}

.language .dropdown-menu:after {
    content: "\f0d8";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 38px;
    top: -34px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
    margin: 15px 18px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background: none;
}

.navbar-default .booking .btn-default,
.navbar-default .booking .btn-default:hover,
.navbar-default .booking .btn-default:focus {
    font-size: 19px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: 0;
    background: #ff2a00;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
}

.navbar-default .booking .btn-default a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15.5px 31px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    top: 134%;
    left: -65%;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="Logo">
         Logo
        </a> 
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="item active">
            <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" title="Apartments">Apartments</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" title="Rates">Rates</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" title="Location">Location</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-->
   </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try to click on another menu card, for example, "Rates", nothing happens, right? Also I need, when click on another menu card, add class active on that menu item

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav:hover>.active:not(:hover) > a {
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```